# yii2 Deleting multiple Rows in GridView using Checkbox

Tags: yii2

How can I use in GridView delete selected object,in Yii 2 Framework such as following image:

[image]

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    'id',
    'name',
    'created_at:datetime',
    // ...
],
```

]) ?>

Answer (score 2):

Add checkbox action column in `gridView` like

```
<?= GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'columns' => [
      [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($data) {
                return ['value' => $data->id];
            },
      ],
      'id',
      'name',
      'created_at:datetime',
      // ...
   ],
 ]) ?>
```

And Now Access the selected `id` in your controller like

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
  public function actionHear()
  {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['selection']))
    {
       ".........Your Code Hear.........."
     }
  }
}
```